# PATH settings for Oracle database

Tags: oracle

I have a laptop with Centos 7. I installed Oracle 12C database on it.The oracle user is `oracle` and the sid is `orcl`.
How can a user that is not `oracle` user run the `sqlplus` program directly ?

The .bash_profile for the `oracle` user is

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ] ; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

export TMP
export TMPDIR=$TMP
export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=servera.localdomain
export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/11.1.0/db_1
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
export TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/. local/bin:$HOME/bin
export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64
export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
```

question: Do I need to have these variable exports for every user in their .bash_profile file ?

Comment: Why do people not use `source /usr/local/bin/oraenv`?  Yes, it can run non-interactively.  (Read the script for HOWTO)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the minimum:

```
export ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
```

Or use `oraenv`. Add the below in `/etc/oratab` if it is not already there:

```
orcl:/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1:N
```

Then interactively:

```
. oraenv
ORACLE_SID = [oracle] ? orcl
The Oracle base has been set to /u01/app/oracle
```

Or from a script:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH # default path for oraenv, in case your PATH does not include it
export ORAENV_ASK=NO
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
. oraenv
```

It is not mandatory to set these in the profile, users can set themselves it when needed.